# Unable to parse required data from nested arrays in json using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

When I tried with my script, I do get response but can't parse the Name and Email from this response as I never worked with json arrays. Hope there is somebody to give me an idea. I tried with:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
url = 'https://oresapp.asicanada.net/ores.imis.services/api/member/?'
address = '&callback=angular.callbacks._0&city=&companyName=&personName='
xhr = url + urlencode({'address':address})
j = requests.get(xhr).json()
print(j)
```

And the partial response is like:

```
[{'EmailAddress': '', 'Zip': '', 'Members': [{'Fax': '', 'FirstLastName': 'Ryley Reat', 'Id': 46648, 'FirstName': 'Ryley', 'FullName': 'Ryley Reat', 'Email': 'zolo@zolo.ca', 'LastName': 'Reat', 'LocationId': 46647, 'Phone': '', 'WebSite': ''}], 'ProvinceCode': '', 'CityRanking': 1.0, 'WorkPhone': '', 'Website': '', 'GeoCodeAddress': 'CANADA', 'GeoCode': {'latitude': 56.130366, 'longitude': -106.346771}, 'City': '', 'FullAddress': 'CANADA', 'Id': 46647, 'Fax': '', 'CompanyNameRanking': 1.0, 'Company': 'Zolo Realty Inc.', 'Country': 'Canada', 'BrokerName': ' '}, {'EmailAddress': '', 'Zip': 'T3H 4W2', 'Members': [{'Fax': '', 'FirstLastName': 'David SandBrand', 'Id': 46646, 'FirstName': 'David', 'FullName': 'David SandBrand', 'Email': 'david@sandbrand.com', 'LastName': 'SandBrand', 'LocationId': 46645, 'Phone': '', 'WebSite': ''}], 'ProvinceCode': 'AB', 'CityRanking': 1.0, 'WorkPhone': '', 'Website': '', 'GeoCodeAddress': '146 West Springs Pl SW Calgary, AB  T3H 4W2 CANADA', 'GeoCode': {'latitude': 51.0626195, 'longitude': -114.1907432}, 'City': 'Calgary', 'FullAddress': '146 West Springs Pl SW Calgary, AB  T3H 4W2 CANADA', 'Id': 46645, 'Fax': '', 'CompanyNameRanking': 1.0, 'Company': 'Damecca Holdings Ltd', 'Country': 'Canada', 'BrokerName': ' '}, {'EmailAddress': 'c.reception@century21.ca', 'Zip': 'S9V 0N7', 'Members': [{'Fax': '', 'FirstLastName': 'Alex Palmer', 'Id': 45347, 'FirstName': 'Alex', 'FullName': 'Alex Palmer', 'Email': 'alex.palmer@century21.ca', 'LastName': 'Palmer', 'LocationId': 37526, 'Phone': '(306) 821-0138', 'WebSite': ''}, {'Fax': '', 'FirstLastName': 'Becky Hofer', 'Id': 45379, 'FirstName': 'Becky', 'FullName': 'Becky Hofer', 'Email': 'becky.hofer@century21.ca', 'LastName': 'Hofer', 'LocationId': 37526, 'Phone': '(306) 830-9740', 'WebSite': ''}, {'Fax': '', 'FirstLastName': 'Cheryl Fairweather', 'Id': 45346, 'FirstName': 'Cheryl', 'FullName': 'Cheryl Fairweather', 'Email': 'cheryl.fariweather@century21.ca', 'LastName': 'Fairweather', 'LocationId': 37526, 'Phone': '(780) 808-9406', 'WebSite': ''}, {'Fax': '', 'FirstLastName': 'Chris Hassall', 'Id': 45334, 'FirstName': 'Chris', 'FullName': 'Chris Hassall', 'Email': 'chris.hassall@century21.ca', 'LastName': 'Hassall', 'LocationId': 37526, 'Phone': '(780) 871-3838', 'WebSite': ''}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
url = 'https://oresapp.asicanada.net/ores.imis.services/api/member/?'
address = '&callback=angular.callbacks._0&city=&companyName=&personName='
xhr = url + urlencode({'address':address})
j = requests.get(xhr).json()
for item in j:
    print(item['Members'][0]['FirstLastName'],item['Members'][0]['Email'], item['Members'][0]['Phone'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Write before the print(j)

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Run your script and then the console will wait for commands, there you can write commands, start playing with your json, remember that a Json are tuples with dictionaries, that can have more tupels or more dictionaries inside, so you will end with something like

print (j[1]['EmailAddress'])